# NSolve super slow for a parameter scan

Tags: equation-solving

I am using NSolve to solve two equations for two variables while scanning through several values of angles. The strange thing is that when I manual enter a value for the angle and Nsolve the answer is instantly found. But, when I scan through a bunch of angles it takes forever (/.theta->{0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5...etc})

SLOW:

```
be[theta_, 
   r_] := {{Cos[theta], r*Sin[theta], 0, 0, 0, 
   r (1 - Cos[theta])}, {-1/r Sin[theta], Cos[theta], 0, 0, 0, 
   Sin[theta]}, {0, 0, 1, r*theta, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
   0}, {-Sin[theta], -r*(1 - Cos[theta]), 0, 0, 
   1, -r*(theta - Sin[theta])}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
ed[theta_, 
   r_] := {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1/r Tan[theta], 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1/r Tan[theta], 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
dr[x_] := {{1, x, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, x, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}

   lb1 = 0.2;
   lb2 = 0.2;
   theta1 = 0.16683602;
   theta2 = 0.063;
   (*theta3=0.043;*)
   r1 = lb1/theta1;
   r2 = lb1/theta2;
   r3 = lb2/(theta2 + theta3);
   r4 = lb2/theta3;

system = 
   be[theta3, r4].ed[theta3, r4].dr[
   g].ed[-theta3, -r3].be[-theta2 - 
   theta3, -r3].ed[-theta2, -r3].dr[f].ed[theta2, r2].be[
   theta2, r2].dr[1.0926].be[theta1, r1].ed[theta1, r1].dr[
   d].ed[-theta1, -r1].be[-theta1, -r1];

Dis = system[[1, 6]];
Com = system[[5, 6]];  

g = 2.5;
NSolve[{Dis == 0, Com == 0.025}, {d, f}]/.theta3 -> {0.01, 0.02}
```

FAST:

```
be[theta_, 
   r_] := {{Cos[theta], r*Sin[theta], 0, 0, 0, 
   r (1 - Cos[theta])}, {-1/r Sin[theta], Cos[theta], 0, 0, 0, 
   Sin[theta]}, {0, 0, 1, r*theta, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
   0}, {-Sin[theta], -r*(1 - Cos[theta]), 0, 0, 
   1, -r*(theta - Sin[theta])}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
ed[theta_, 
   r_] := {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1/r Tan[theta], 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1/r Tan[theta], 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
dr[x_] := {{1, x, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, x, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}

   lb1 = 0.2;
   lb2 = 0.2;
   theta1 = 0.16683602;
   theta2 = 0.063;
   (*theta3=0.043;*)
   r1 = lb1/theta1;
   r2 = lb1/theta2;
   r3 = lb2/(theta2 + theta3);
   r4 = lb2/theta3;

system = 
   be[theta3, r4].ed[theta3, r4].dr[
   g].ed[-theta3, -r3].be[-theta2 - 
   theta3, -r3].ed[-theta2, -r3].dr[f].ed[theta2, r2].be[
   theta2, r2].dr[1.0926].be[theta1, r1].ed[theta1, r1].dr[
   d].ed[-theta1, -r1].be[-theta1, -r1];

Dis = system[[1, 6]];
Com = system[[5, 6]];  

g = 2.5;
theta3=0.01;
NSolve[{Dis == 0, Com == 0.025}, {d, f}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your first block of code doesn't work is that you make the replacement for `theta3` **after** invoking `NSolve` on the system of equations. At the time it is invoked, the system of equations doesn't have a numerical value for `theta3` to work with.

So you simply have to change the last line as follows (copying the whole first code block for consistency):

```
Clear[theta3]

be[theta_, 
  r_] := {{Cos[theta], r*Sin[theta], 0, 0, 0, 
   r (1 - Cos[theta])}, {-1/r Sin[theta], Cos[theta], 0, 0, 0, 
   Sin[theta]}, {0, 0, 1, r*theta, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
   0}, {-Sin[theta], -r*(1 - Cos[theta]), 0, 0, 
   1, -r*(theta - Sin[theta])}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
ed[theta_, 
  r_] := {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1/r Tan[theta], 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1/r Tan[theta], 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
dr[x_] := {{1, x, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, x, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}

lb1 = 0.2;
lb2 = 0.2;
theta1 = 0.16683602;
theta2 = 0.063;
(*theta3=0.043;*)
r1 = lb1/theta1;
r2 = lb1/theta2;
r3 = lb2/(theta2 + theta3);
r4 = lb2/theta3;

system = be[theta3, r4].ed[theta3, r4].dr[
    g].ed[-theta3, -r3].be[-theta2 - theta3, -r3].ed[-theta2, -r3].dr[
    f].ed[theta2, r2].be[theta2, r2].dr[1.0926].be[theta1, r1].ed[
    theta1, r1].dr[d].ed[-theta1, -r1].be[-theta1, -r1];

Dis = system[[1, 6]];
Com = system[[5, 6]];

g = 2.5;
Table[NSolve[{Dis == 0, Com == 0.025} /. theta3 -> angle, {d, 
   f}], {angle, {0.01, 0.02}}]

(*
==> {{{d -> 0.446548, f -> 1.96807}}, {{d -> 0.383928, 
   f -> 2.2263}}}
*)
```

Here I replaced your last line by a `Table` that runs over the desired values and makes the replacements in the equations *inside* `NSolve`. This runs very fast, just like your second code block.

Comment: Hi Jens, thank so much, but I want the answer to be outputted like: d->{1,2,3,4,5}, f->{1,2,3,4,5}....This is how the output would be for a non-trig equation solving. Any ideas?

Comment: That just requires some reshaping of the result. E.g., if the output from above is called `ans`, then one could do  `Thread[{d,f}->({d,f}/.Flatten[ans,1])]` (where `Thread` adds the `Rule` arrow to each list of `d` and `f` values, resp.

Comment: Whenever I try to scan more than two values for theta3 I get the error:"Objects of unequal length in {d,f}->" Any help? I have about sixty values to scan...